# spree shipping cost don't change with multiple items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, demo

I am using `spree` online demo ,having some issues related to shipping cost calculation.While
trying to add a single product to cart and checkout ,then all works
fine, the shipping charge added to the total amount correctly.But the
problem is that when am **trying to checkout using multiple number of
same type product the shipping charge remains as the same for single
product**,the shipping charge must change according to products count.
Thanks in advnc
Rajith

Answer (score 1):

you need to use another shipping calculator for that, i don't know if spree includes one for your desired behavior, or if there is one available as an extension. nevertheless, writing calculators is extremely simple, the spree docs provide good information about this topic:

http://guides.spreecommerce.com/shipping.html